# how to give callback function to the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, callback, dispatcher

I need to use callback function to do some post procesing tasks when the function started with the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke finishes. However i could  not find any parameter in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke  to accept a callback. Is it possible to give a callback function to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `DispatcherOperation` object returned by `BeginInvoke` has a `Completed` event on it. Subscribe to that to perform operations upon completion:

```
var dispatcherOp = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( /* your method here */);
dispatcherOp.Completed += (s, e) => { /* callback code here */ };
```

There's a chance the operation will complete before you subscribe, so you can test the `Status` property for completion after as well:

```
if (dispatcherOp.Status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed) { ... }
```

It's possible for the operation to be aborted as well, so handling/testing for `Aborted` may also be appropriate.

Comment: Note that this is not available on Windows Phone 7, 8 and  Silverlight :(