# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke always return DispatcherOperationStatus.Pending status

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I try to update `ObservableCollection` asynchronously using the following code in my WPF project:

```
if (Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    if (Dispatcher.Thread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped && !Dispatcher.Thread.IsBackground)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { ChangeCollectionByAction(action); }), null);
    }
    else
    {
        var op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ChangeCollectionByAction(action); }), null);
        var status = op.Status;
        while (status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
        {
            status = op.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunetly status alway equals `DispatcherOperationStatus.Pending`.

p.s.: may be my problem that i use ElementHost on WinForms project?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `Dispatcher.Invoke`?  There's no reason to use BeginInvoke and then immediately wait on the results...

Comment: @Reed Copsey, loop with getting status of DispatecherOperation only for demonstration, that status is always Pedding.

Comment: Is your dispatcher thread a background thread?

Comment: Yes, using ElementHost inside WinForms probably does something have to do with it. Have you tried to reproduce it in a standalone WPF project?

Comment: @Сергей Шулик I think that your dispather is busy with some other long-running operation. It would have the same result

Answer (score 12):

If you want something to run once an asynchronous operation is done, you should use it's `Completed` event.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354414/302677) answer for an example

> ```
> var dispatcherOp = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( /* your method here */);
> dispatcherOp.Completed += (s, e) => { /* callback code here */ };
> ```
>
> There's a chance the operation will complete before you subscribe, so
>   you can test the Status property for completion after as well:
>
> ```
> if (dispatcherOp.Status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed) { ... }
> ```

As for the actual problem, I'm not sure without being able to reproduce it. If I had to hazard a guess, it would be that your loop is tying up the current `Dispatcher` thread, so it can't process the `BeginInvoke` operation you told it to process, so it will always sit at `Pending`.

Answer (score 4):

The status of your operation seems to be stale because enum is a value type and you store it in a variable. 
Changing your code to this should fix your problem :

```
    var op = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ChangeCollectionByAction(action); }), null);
    while (op.Status!= DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
    {
        status = op.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
```

In fact you could replace all your code just by this single line:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ChangeCollectionByAction(action))).Wait();
```

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion with Wait could be simplified with just `Dispatcher.Invoke` as Reed Copsey wrote in comments.

Comment: Your 1st suggestion seems to be the only way to call a WMI query from a call stack started by WindowsFormsHost and wait for the answer. 2nd suggestion doesn't actually work in that case, maybe it's not completely Async

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is not awaitable.

If .NET 4.5 is available for you, then you can use [`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync):

```
if (Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ChangeCollectionByAction(action));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `Dispatcher.Thread.ThreadState` value before call the `BeginInvoke`?

I think the problem that Dispatcher thread is *Stopped*. So calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in stopped thread will cause infinity *Pending* status because it can't run anything.